# Working with arrays within objects in expressions

Tags: mule, mule-el

Good morning!  I'm trying to create a Web API using Mule that will transform one JSON-based request from system A into another JSON-based format, invoke a Web API on system B using the transformed JSON, take the JSON response from system B and transform it to some JSON that system A can understand, and return that result in the response to the original HTTP request.  I have it mostly working, but I can't figure out how to reference arrays within properties.  Here's the JSON going into the `Expression` component:

```
{
    "FooObjects":
    [
        {
            "FooPropertyOne": "value for property one"
          , "FooPropertyTwo": "value for property two"
          , "FooPropertyThree": "value for property three"
          , "FooId": 22031
          , "FooBarRelationships":
            [
                {
                    "FooBarRelationshipId": 18014
                  , "RelationshipProperty": "value for rel property"
                  , "Bar": { "BarPropertyOne": "value for property one", "BarId": 11379 }
                }
              , {
                    "FooBarRelationshipId": 18015
                  , "RelationshipProperty": "value for rel property"
                  , "Bar": { "BarPropertyOne": "value for property one", "BarId": 10001 }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's the result I want:

```
{
    "FooObjects":
    [
        {
            "FooPropertyOne": "value for property one"
          , "FooPropertyTwo": "value for property two"
          , "FooPropertyThree": "value for property three"
          , "FooId": 22031
          , "FooUrl": "https://server/path/to/foo?FooId=22013"
          , "Bars":
            [
                { "BarPropertyOne": "value for property one", "BarId": 11379 }
              , { "BarPropertyOne": "value for property one", "BarId": 10001 }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's the expression component:

```
    <expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[payload =
[
    "FooObjects": ([
        "FooPropertyOne": $.FooPropertyOne
      , "FooPropertyTwo": $.FooPropertyTwo
      , "FooPropertyThree": $.FooPropertyThree
      , "FooId": $.FooId
      , "FooURl": "https://server/path/to/foo?FooId=" + $.FooId
      , "Bars": $.FooBarRelationships
    ] in payload.FooObjects)
];]]></expression-component>
```

I've been guessing at the syntax to put in place of `$.FooBarRelationships`.  The best I can come up with is `(['BarPropertyOne':$.Bar.BarPropertyOne]in $.FooBarRelationships)`.  This gets me:

```
[Error: could not access: Bar; in class: java.util.LinkedHashMap]
[Near : {... $.Bar.BarPropertyOne....}]
             ^
```

How can I perform this transformation?  If I leave out the part about `Bars`, everything works fine, apart from not getting all of the data I need.  Thanks!

**edit:** I changed the example to show the multiplicity more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I've been able to make this work is via a function:

```
<configuration>
    <expression-language>
        <global-functions>
            def makeBars(fooBarRelationships) {
              (['BarPropertyOne':$.Bar.BarPropertyOne] in fooBarRelationships)
            }
        </global-functions>
    </expression-language>
</configuration>
```

then in  flow I can use:

```
<expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[payload =
    [
        "FooObjects": ([
            "FooPropertyOne": $.FooPropertyOne
          , "FooPropertyTwo": $.FooPropertyTwo
          , "FooPropertyThree": $.FooPropertyThree
          , "FooId": $.FooId
          , "FooURl": "https://server/path/to/foo?FooId=" + $.FooId
          , "Bars": makeBars($.FooBarRelationships)
        ] in payload.FooObjects)
    ];]]></expression-component>
```

Comment: Thanks, @David.  I ended up writing nested loops, and that works quickly enough for me.  I'll mark this answer as correct, since I think it's a good approach.  I did find a Mule MVEL Expression Language reference in my search for an answer.  Perhaps this will benefit someone else who might stumble upon this question in the future: http://mulesoft.github.io/mule-module-mvel/usage.html.

Comment: For the record, this is the doc of the now obsolete `mule-module-mvel` which was initially used to add MVEL to Mule before Mule embedded in its core as MEL. This doc is still perfect for MVEL of course. Note that the official MEL doc is here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+MEL

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Is there documentation for MEL that is as comprehensive as the link I provided?  I'm looking especially for syntax documentation.  The new stuff, for example, doesn't describe how to use a loop.